# Where would you look to find out problem with Xdebug+Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, xdebug

When I'm listening to port 9000 of my host machine (with `tcpdump`) and making request to docker container's URL (just http://localhost:80), I see 2 packets captured at that moment. But when I'm listening with PhpStorm or [xdebug's command line debug client](https://xdebug.org/download#dbgpClient) (with no arguments), they don't react in any way.

When I disable xdebug in container (by commenting out `xdebug.remote_enable=1`) and make request, nothing comes to port 9000 of the host, which makes me think that xdebug is working.

When I run same code locally, same xdebug command line tool (also with no arguments) does start debugging, which makes me think that I use correct tools.

I did try following IPs as `xdebug.remote_host` in container's `xdebug.ini` file (same result):

- 172.17.0.1 (returned by running `ip -4 addr show docker0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'` on host)
- 172.18.0.1 (returned by running `/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'` in container)
- ≈10 others, which I don't remember how I got (tried lots of things)

What am I missing? And what should I check?

---

On host machine:

```
> php -v
PHP 7.4.6 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 10:02:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
    with blackfire v1.34.0~linux-x64-non_zts74, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfire



> sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ":9000"
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      20230/./dbgpClient
```

In Docker container:

```
> php -v
PHP 7.0.33-27+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Apr 19 2020 08:00:54) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-27+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.8.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans



> cat /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 172.17.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /var/www/html/xdebug.log



> ls -la /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 May  5 10:46 /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini



> php -m |grep xdebug
xdebug



> cat /var/www/html/xdebug.log
[6] Log opened at 2020-05-22 11:47:38
[6] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 172.17.0.1:9000.
[6] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
[6] Log closed at 2020-05-22 11:47:38
```

Content of incorrect captured packets (sent from container, without dbgp client turned on):

```
> sudo tcpdump -i any -vv port 9000
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
10:25:21.213336 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22110, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.220.2.56070 > machine.9000: Flags [S], cksum 0x48ec (incorrect -> 0xdbca), seq 3695390688, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3734519707 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:25:21.213351 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22110, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    192.168.220.2.56070 > machine.9000: Flags [S], cksum 0x48ec (incorrect -> 0xdbca), seq 3695390688, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3734519707 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
^C
2 packets captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Content of correct captured packets (sent from host, also without dbgp client listening):

```
> sudo tcpdump -i any -vv port 9000
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
12:19:39.842408 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 61242, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    localhost.60404 > localhost.9000: Flags [S], cksum 0xfe30 (incorrect -> 0x158b), seq 743066778, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 3009412885 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:19:39.842418 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    localhost.9000 > localhost.60404: Flags [R.], cksum 0x29cc (correct), seq 0, ack 743066779, win 0, length 0
^C
2 packets captured
12 packets received by filter
1 packet dropped by kernel
```

(timestamps in different outputs differ, because I strip repeating parts)

Comment: 1) Try to use 9001 port to avoid any possible collisions with php-fpm that you may also have there. 2) I assume it's Linux. For Mac & Windows you can use special `host.docker.internal` name (not available on Linux) https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-385698947 3) Does xdebug log has anything to say about it? Where it tries to connect to and what response it has? 4) Just in case: SELinux or alike may completely block outgoing xdebug connections (at very least saw it few times with non virtual environments with Apache web server).

Comment: 5) Just in case: also check your actual xdebug settings (from `phpinfo()` output) -- in case if there more settings passed the other way (e.g. env variable XDEBUG_CONFIG or alike). Sadly no hints on actual docker network troubleshooting from me.

Comment: Thanks, 1) tried port 9001, same bad result. 2) Yes, both are Linux machines: host Linux Mint 19.3, container Ubuntu 16.04 3) There is "Time-out connecting to client" in logs. BTW, thanks for the tip, I'll attach logs to the question 4) I'm not using one, and seems like packets are not completely blocked, just "ignored" by dbgp client 5) seems like basic config values (host, port) are correct. But thanks, I'll try to compare them with local (working) `phpinfo` to find some differences/tips